# How to replace a React component with another one when its state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-image

I'm pretty new with React and this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

I want to show a large image that takes 3-4 seconds to load, so i want to show user a loader, which is achievable using ReactImage from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image

Then i want to add an option to zoom, but the zoom function should only be available after the image is loaded successfully, so i'm planning to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-magnify

However there's no events or possible way to make the 2 communicate their states with each other so that in my `render()` function i can choose to use either ReactImage or ReactImageMagnify.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is some pseudocode, i have a react component called `Preview`, and it has a `render()` function that returns either ReactImage or ReactImageMagnify

```
export class Preview extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        // if image is not yet loaded then return ReactImage
        return(
                <ReactImage
                    src={this.getPreviewUrl()}
                    className=""
                    style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
                    alt=""
                    loader={<LoadingImage />}
                />
        )

        //if not, return ReactImageMagnify
        return(
                <ReactImageMagnify {...{
                    smallImage: {
                        alt: 'Chef Works',
                        isFluidWidth: true,
                        src: 'smallimage.png'
                    },
                    bigImage: {
                        alt: 'Chef Works',
                        isFluidWidth: true,
                        src: 'bigimage.png'
                    }
                }}/>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets.

Comment: It doesn't look like `react-image` has any interface to tell when it loaded the image. Which means this will be tough for you to accomplish if you depend on that package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized all i needed from the ReactImage was just the loading icon when image is not yet loaded, so i implemented the same behavior based on Travis James' answer and have a conditional display property for the ReactImageMagnify instead. Code is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactImageMagnify from 'react-image-magnify';
import { LoadingImage } from 'ui/component/loading-image';

import styles from './style.css';

export const PreviewWithZoom = ({imageLink, zoomImageLink}) => {
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [loadedZoom, setLoadedZoom] = useState(false);

    return(<>
        {loaded ? null : <LoadingImage />}
        <img
            style={loaded && !loadedZoom ? {} : {display: 'none'}}
            src={imageLink}
            onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
            alt=''
        />
        <img
            style={{display: 'none'}}
            src={zoomImageLink}
            onLoad={() => setLoadedZoom(true)}
            alt=''
            />

        <div style={loaded && loadedZoom ? {} : {display: 'none'}}>
            <ReactImageMagnify {...{
                className: styles.previewZoom,
                smallImage: {
                    src: imageLink,
                    width: 670,
                    height: 670
                },
                largeImage: {
                    src: zoomImageLink,
                    width: 1500,
                    height: 1500,
                }
            }}/>
        </div>
    </>);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `loading` state value that you update based on the result of your image fetch call:

```
const ImageComponent = ({imageResult}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
       if(imageResult !== null) {
            setLoading(false)
       }
    },[imageResult])

    return {
       {loading ? <Loader /> : <Image src={imageResult} />
    }
}
```

Comment: While this didn't solve my problem, it actually inspired me to re-think how to achieve the behavior i wanted. Thanks a lot!